# How can I check if a library was compiled with -fno-rtti?

Tags: c++, linker, rtti

Assume a simple file `bla.cpp`:

```
struct MyClass {
  virtual int foo(int x);
  virtual ~MyClass();
};


int MyClass::foo(int x) { return x + 23; }
MyClass::~MyClass() {}
```

Build into a shared library with

```
g++ -c -fPIC bla.cpp
g++ -shared -o bla.so bla.o
```

will usually contain some `type_info` symbol because RTTI is enabled by default on gcc. However, if I build with

```
g++ -c -fPIC -fno-rtti bla.cpp
```

the `type_info` will be missing.

Is there a simple, reliable way (on `gcc` or `clang`) to check if a library has been built with `-fno-rtti` or `-frtti`? I ask because today I stared at the infamous `undefined reference to type_info` and it took me a moment to understand that this was cause by a library I was linking against being built with `-fno-rtti`.

Comment: Well why don't you use `<dynamic_cast>` and see if you get a compilation error? Or do you need to conduct this test during runtime?

Comment: @barakmanos This is not going to work. If I use `dynamic_cast` my code breaks depending on my setting of `f(no)rtti`. I'm wondering about a library I'm linking against (here inheritance is usually enough to break compilation). I really want to know this during `configure` time to set up parts of my build correctly or perhaps warn about it.

Comment: If you need this for configuration, do as GNU autoconf does: Write a minimal proggie that does the checking and build that one. If the build (or perhaps run) fails or not tells you what you need to know.

Comment: @vonbrand Yes, that sounds good. Could you add it as an answer?

Answer (score 11):

If a class has virtual. functions, it should have type info. Do `nm -C libname.so` and watch for "vtable for", "typeinfo for", and "typeinfo name for". Example:

```
00000000 b .bss
00000000 d .data
00000000 r .eh_frame
00000000 r .rdata$_ZTI3Foo
00000000 r .rdata$_ZTS3Foo
00000000 r .rdata$_ZTV3Foo
00000000 r .rdata$zzz
00000000 t .text
00000000 T Foo::foo()
00000000 R typeinfo for Foo
00000000 R typeinfo name for Foo
00000000 R vtable for Foo
         U vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info
```

If you have `vtable` but not `typeinfo`, this is compiled with `-fno-rtti`. Example:

```
00000000 b .bss
00000000 d .data
00000000 r .eh_frame
00000000 r .rdata$_ZTV3Foo
00000000 r .rdata$zzz
00000000 t .text
00000000 T Foo::foo()
00000000 R vtable for Foo
```

If you don't have any virtual functions, you cannot tell (and should not care).

Comment: if you strip symbols, do you still get this information in the library?

Comment: Can I assume this to be the same across different compilers? I wouldn't think so, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @BЈовић You cannot link with a stripped library, but you can try `nm -D`.

Comment: @pmr no, but I think the microsoft compiler has similar symbols for vtable and typeinfo.

Comment: After some thought, I realized that my comment was a nonsense. Of course, this info is there even after stripping the library. I am not sure what you meant with "can't link", but I was thinking of just stripping debug symbols.

Comment: @BЈовић no, it's not nonsense. Stripping removes info necessary for `ld` so linking will fail; but symbols necessary for `ld.so` remain so you can still dlopen and load it.

Comment: Great answer and to the point. I guess that all those C++ ABI changes eventually resulted in library dependencies issues being easier to debug :)

Answer (score 3):

If you need this for configuration, do as GNU autoconf does: Write a minimal proggie that does the checking and build that one. Whether the build (or perhaps a run) fails or not tells you what you need to know.